# How to open the viewer pane in browser?

Tags: r, rstudio, expss

Just a simple question that I couldn't find an answer. I just updated my R Studio and R, and one function that I used a lot was opening the results in Viewer pane in my browser.

For example, with the resulting tables from packages like sjPlot or expss, I used the "Show in new window" to visualize the tables in Chrome or other default browser. Don't know if this was set by a old package, but I can't get this result right now. Actually, when I click this option, nothing is happening.

When I change to my old R version 3.6.2, I can use the "show in new window", but can't make to work in the version 4.0.1.

Anyone would know how can I get this function again?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you got any work around?

Comment: Hi @data9, so I also posted this issue at Reddit and one user (jmcphers) pointed to a post at github, take a look: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7152. Don't know if they fixed that, but for now I'm using the newest R Studio version, with the 3.6.3 R version.

Answer (score 1):

options(viewr=NULL) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i use browseURL instead of rstudioapi::viewer open file in browser directly.

```
browseURL(sprintf("%s/test.html", tempdir()))
```

if your file not in tempdir(), you should copy it to tempdir() first:

```
system(sprintf("cp %s %s", test_file, tempdir()))
```